# Making a Count that takes into consideration null check - What should i call it? SafeCount?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

```
    public static int SafeCount<T>(this IList list)
    {
        return list != null ? list.Count : 0;
    }
```

What I want to ask is what should I call this method? SafeCount? NullSafeCount?

Can you come up with something more short yet non-ambigous?

Comment: I would suggest an overload for `IEnumerable<T>` as well (so will work for all collections) and changing this one to `ICollection<T>` to take in a wider selection of collection types with `Count` property.

Comment: BuggyCount, I'd say.  CountIfNotNull describes what it does.

Comment: @Richard: Depends on the usage. Because he might not want to enumerate the collection using the count extension.

Comment: This is the wrong code to write.  You should write an `IList.EmptyIfNull` method and pass your list to that, then take the count -- not a `CountZeroIfNull` method.

Comment: @Yuriy: Remember overloads are resolved on the static type, and `Enumerable.Count()` checks for `ICollection<T>`, so even if the static type is `IEnumerable<T>` the collection's own implementation will be used if possible.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I'll do that. Also I'm looking for names for this method, that is all.

Answer (score 2):

To align with other methods in the framework I would call it `GetCountOrDefault` or possible `CountOrDefault`.  Similar methods from which I would look to for predecence.

- `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`
- `Enumerable.SingleOrDefault`
- `Enumerable.LastOrDefault`
- `Enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault`
- `Nullable.GetValueOrDefault`

Another option is to encode the ambiguity in the return type instead of the method name by having it return a `int?` instead of an `int`.

```
public static int? GetCount(this IList list) { 
  return list != null ? (int?)list.Count : null;
}
```

Comment: I see where you're going with this .. hmm don;t know how I Feel about it thoiugh.

Comment: @halviingston, I agree it's a bit odd at first.  But without a compelling reason I would favor precedenc over a new name.  In these examples the `Nullable<T>` is the most compelling for me as it describes a very similar scenario.

Comment: @halviingston added another suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It might just be linq's influence on me, but I would be tempted to call it 'CountOrDefault'. Not really shorter though...

(side note:  Why IList and not IEnumerable? Just curious)

Comment: In that case you can use IEnumerable's Count() Function.  I can understand not wanting to materialize the IEnumerable, but you have to do that anyway to create the IList necessary to use the above function.

Comment: One possible shorter name:  'CountOr0'